# Как установить Prettier? в пакете create react-app my-app --typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Я установил React TypeScript с помощью пакета create react-app my-app --typescript, никак не могу установить после этого Prettier, Как установить Prettier ?

Answer (score 0):

```
## Если еще не создан, делаем проект:
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript

## Переходим в папку с проектом
cd my-app

## Устанавливаем пакеты
npm install --save-dev husky lint-staged prettier
```

Открываем *package.json* и расширяем конфигурацию:

```
{
  // ...

  "scripts": {

    // ...

    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "prettify": "prettier --write './src/**/*.{js,json,jsx,ts,tsx,css,scss}'"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,json,jsx,ts,tsx,css,scss}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  },

  // ...

}
```

Теперь при каждом коммите `prettier` будет форматировать измененные файлы, а для форматирования всего проекта можно испоьзовать команду:

```
npm run prettify
```

Comment: Я всё сделала как ты сказал но Prettier не работает никак

Comment: Не работает никак это что значит? Что пишет в консоли после команды `npm run prettyfy`?

Comment: Это значит что я 3 раза пробовал,    npm  ERR! missing script: prettyfy
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     prettify

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vigo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-09T10_59_06_039Z-debug.log

Comment: Опечатка `npm run prettify`

Comment: я снял видео посмотри сам. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DVBBakwdGs&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Исправил ответ, была опечатка

Comment: все равно не работает

Comment: Какая ошибка? так же я не могу подсказать